# Running a mod_wsgi (Flask) app and a non mod_wsgi app on same Apache server

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I inherited a web app running on an AWS EC2 Windows instance and WAMP Server via python CGI scripts (Apache2.4).  I'm looking to convert the web app over to Flask but cannot afford to take down the existing one while I test/roll out my Flask app.

All of the current scripts are located in the WAMP www folder and are accessed on the internet as IP address/'filename.extension'

Is there a way for me to configure Virtualhosts to allow me to run the existing app in the www folder and host my Flask app using mod_WSGI on the same Apache server?

Am I best off just setting up a new AWS instance to host my Flask app and just move everything over?

Thanks

Comment: I would personally setup a new EC2 instance and run some flavor of Linux. Kill two birds with one stone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mount the WSGI application at a sub URL so doesn't interfere. Alternatively use `AddHandler` and specify WSGI scripts use a `.wsgi` extension so doesn't interfere with existing Python CGI scripts if they use a `.py` extension.

For more details about options read:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/configuration-guidelines.html